# Shapes getting distorted while displaying in LCD

Tags: lcd, stm32f4

I am trying to display a circle in my 800*480 LCD (TIANMA). But an oval shape is getting displayed instead of circle. 
The length of LCD is 15.5 cm. Assuming square pixels length to breadth ratio should be 800/480. From this I got breadth as 9.3 cm but actual breadth is 8.3 cm.

Is it because of this problem the figure is getting distorted.

I have tried with Ampire LCD (640*480) with length breadth of same ratio.
It is displaying exact dimensions.

Comment: "Assuming square pixels" may be your mistake.

Comment: If it is not a square pixel , while displaying an image of a square with a specific dimension , say 100x100 pixel it will show a rectangle . How can i avoid this problem?

Comment: In this case whatever image which is displayed in different LCD may look different in this LCD which is not desired..

Comment: ways to avoid it: get differnt lcd, or display rectangles and ellispis instead.

Comment: Pre-distort the image in software. One way is called interpolation. You only need to apply it to one axis.

Comment: Every screen is different, and these days they may be applying their own corrections / conversions / scaling depending on the input type - some may assume the input is 4:3 and try to stretch it to widescreen, or the other way round, etc. etc.

Comment: @JohnU Can I correct this in LCD driver?? I didn't find any parameter regarding the size of pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294571.aspx

I got this link which explains my problem. But don't know how to overcome this .
I may have to change my pixel ratio of each picture I am using and scale each shape proportionately. I would rather prefer to use a different LCD with pixel aspect ratio 1:1.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-images-video.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to pay attention to the specs for your two displays. The first is an 800 x 480, while the second (which acts as you expect) is a 640 x 480.

Your problem is not that the display pixels are not square - they are. It's just that you're sending drive signals which only display 640 pixels in a line. The problem child is looking at this signal and modifying the signal so that a line of 640 pixels is mapped onto 800 pixels, and the original pixels are getting stretched to fit in the display.

The display has no way of knowing what aspect ratio you want, and it's assuming you want to use the entire width of the display. Since you're smarter than an LCD display, it's up to you to cater to its limitations, not the other way around. Reformat your display driver to provide an 800 x 480 display and you'll be fine. Of course, you'll probably give your 640 x 480 display heartburn, but that can't be helped.

Comment: I have already edited the driver according to the new specs (800x480) and made the Hsync , Vsync etc changes according to new LCD datasheet . After this I am getting the problem.

Comment: Put it this way. Let's say you create an image with a 1-pixel-wide vertical bar at horizontal locations 0,199,399,599, and 799. How many bars show up on the LCD? If it's not 5, you and the LCD have different opinions on how it needs to be driven.

Comment: According to current implementation, it shows 5 vertical bars as you told

Comment: So exactly how much distortion are you getting on a square?

Comment: Distortion is same as the pixel pitch ration H/V.Please see my answer.

Comment: So in other words you do not have square pixels. "Is it because of this problem the figure is getting distorted." Yes.